# Blackberry VerticalFieldManager with fixed size : Scroll issue

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to have a full screen UI with a fix header ( a manager with some fields) and a scrollable contents (a list of custom field). The idea is to emulate a kind of scrollable list.

For this I made a custom VerticalFieldManager that accept a maxHeight (the screen height - the header height).

I got the following problems:

- The scroll arrows do not show up (ever)
- On OS 4.7 (Storm), I can scroll lower that the last item, until having nothing on my screen but the header.

My code need to compile with the JDE 4.2.1 & 4.7 and to run on Pearl and Storm. (at worst I could have two version of this class)

I suspect the two problems are related. I probably do something wrong. I looked at a few example/forum and always found similar solution/code. 
Do you guys can tell me what I did wrong?

```
/**
 *  custom class, so we can set a max height (to keep the header visible)
 */
class myVerticalFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager{
private int maxHeight = 0;

myVerticalFieldManager(int _maxHeight){
  super(
   //this provoc an "empty scrollable zone" on Storm
   // but if you don't put it, on other OS, the vertical manager does not scroll at all.
   Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL 

   | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
   ); 
  maxHeight = _maxHeight;
}


protected void sublayout(int width, int height){
        super.sublayout(width, getPreferredHeight());
        setExtent(width, getPreferredHeight());
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Graphics.getScreenWidth();
}

/**
 * allow the manager to use all the given height. (vs auto Height)
 */
public boolean forceMaxHeight = false;
public int getPreferredHeight() {
  if (forceMaxHeight) return maxHeight;
  int m = super.getPreferredHeight();
  if (m > maxHeight) m = maxHeight;
  return m;   
}    

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

protected boolean isUpArrowShown(){
  //TODO: does not seem to work (4.2.1 emulator & 4.5 device). (called with good return value but the arrows are not painted)
  int i = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
  //Trace("isUpArrowShown " + i);
  return i > 0;
  // note: algo not correct, cause the up arrow will be visible event when no field are hidden.
  //       but not so bad, so the user "know" that he can go up.
}

protected boolean isDownArrowShown(){
  int i = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
  return i < getFieldCount();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// note : since 4.6 you can use
// http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/Background.html

public int myBackgroundColor = 0xffffff;
protected void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setBackgroundColor(myBackgroundColor);
    // Clears the entire graphic area to the current background
    g.clear();
    super.paint(g);
}


}
```

any helps is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so,

I came with this workaround for the "empty scrollable zone" problem on STORM
it's ugly and doesn't allow a custom ScrollChangeListener, but it's working on Pearl & Storm

```
implements ScrollChangeListener

 //in constructor:

  setScrollListener(null);
  setScrollListener(this);


private boolean MY_CHANGING_SCROLL = false;
public void scrollChanged(Manager manager, int newHorizontalScroll, int newVerticalScroll){
  if (!MY_CHANGING_SCROLL){
    MY_CHANGING_SCROLL = true;
    myCheckVerticalScroll();
    MY_CHANGING_SCROLL = false;
  }      
}  


protected int myMaxVerticalScrollPosition(){
  int vh = getVirtualHeight();
  int h = getHeight();
  if (vh < h ) return 0; // no scroll
  return vh - h; // don't scroll lower than limit.
}

protected void invCheckVerticalScroll() {
    int i = getVerticalScroll();
    int m = myMaxVerticalScrollPosition();
    if ( i > m){
        i = m;
        setVerticalScroll(i);
    }
}
```

I'm still looking for a solution to the scroll arrows problem...
If anybody got an idea...

Comment: I found out that you can have the same result by an easier way:
- create the screen with the NO_SCROLL flag. (I was missing that);
- add the header as a normal field;
- add a vfm with all your stuff;
--> the arrow will show and the header will stay where it should be. Also, you don't have the ugly shadow under the "setTitle() area"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `setBanner()` instead of add for your header. Then you can add a default `VerticalFieldManager` to the screen and it will scroll normally but won't hide the header. Note that the `MainScreen` delegate manager is a `VerticalScrollManager` so you might not need a second `vfm`.

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
setBanner(hfm)

add(new ButtonField("Hello 1");
add(new ButtonField("Hello 2");
```

...

Comment: the problem with setTitle() is that the lib add a very ugly 4-5px shadow under the title area. I confess: I did not try setBanner().

Answer (score 0):

Hey i did the same thing using a HorizontalFieldManager that contains an image and a title

```
header_img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("header.png");
             title = new LabelField("Welcome",LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT);
             header_manager =  new HorizontalFieldManager()
             {
                 protected void paint(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics graphics)
                    {
                         int y = this.getVerticalScroll();                                      
                         graphics.drawBitmap( 0, y, header_img.getWidth(), header_img.getHeight(), header_img, 0, 0 );
                         graphics.setColor(Color.LEMONCHIFFON);
                         super.paint( graphics );
                    }

                     protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
                     {                      
                        super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 240);

                        Field field = title;
                        layoutChild(field, title.getWidth(), title.getHeight());
                        setPositionChild(field, (Display.getWidth()/2) -10, 13);
                        setExtent(Display.getWidth(),55);

                     }
             };
             header_manager.add(title);
```